# Google translate - Messing up HTML structure - getAttribute in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, google-translate

Hopefully, I will be able to explain.

I have the following HTML:

```
        <aside class="navigation__sidemenu">
            <ul class="navigation__list notranslate">
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#zero-emissie-stadslogistiek">Zero Emissie Stadslogistiek</a></li>
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#kennis">Kennis</a></li>
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#tips-en-tools">Tips &amp; tools</a></li>
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#doe-mee">Doe mee!</a></li>
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#community">Community</a></li>
                <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#over-ons">Over ons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
```

Which works, However when I translate my page to English this happens:

```
<aside class="navigation__sidemenu">
                    <ul class="navigation__list notranslate_">
                        <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#zero-emissie-stadslogistiek"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Zero Emission City Logistics</font></font></a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#kennis"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Knowledge</font></font></a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#tips-en-tools"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;" class="">Tips &amp; tools</font></font></a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#doe-mee"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Join!</font></font></a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__item navigation__link--active"><a class="navigation__link" href="#community"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;" class="">Community</font></font></a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link" href="#over-ons"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">About us</font></font></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
```

It will wrap the A tag text with FONT this leads to breaking my Javascript.

This is the rule giving problems:  l`et clicked = e.target.getAttribute('href');`

My JS file:

```
(() => {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const headerHamburger = header.querySelector('.header__hamburger');

    const headerMenu = header.querySelector('.header__menu');
    const headerMenuText = headerMenu.querySelector('span');

    const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
    const navigationClose = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__close');

    let navigationTitle = document.querySelector('.navigation__title');

    // Capture all elements of <a> output should be in an array
    let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__item');
    let navBox = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__box');

    navItems[0].classList.add('navigation__link--active');
    navBox[0].classList.add('navigation__box--active');

    const RemoveAll = () => {
        navItems.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove('navigation__link--active');
        });

        navBox.forEach((box) => {
            box.classList.remove('navigation__box--active');
        });
    };

    // media query change
    const WidthChange = (mq) => {
        if (!mq.matches) {
            RemoveAll();
        } else {
            RemoveAll();
            navItems[0].classList.add('navigation__link--active');
            navBox[0].classList.add('navigation__box--active');
        }
    };

    // media query event handler
    if (matchMedia) {
        const mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
        mq.addListener(WidthChange);
        WidthChange(mq);
    }

    navItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const active = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--active');

            if (active) {
                active.classList.remove('navigation__link--active');
            }

            e.currentTarget.classList.add('navigation__link--active');

            // Add e in callback function trace the element triggered this event
            // In other words, which button has been clicked
            let clicked = e.target.getAttribute('href');

            // navigationTitle.innerHTML = e.target.innerText;

            // Tricky bit: As per your request they should be at least
            // one default active element otherwise or else will not remove any active class

            if (document.querySelector('.navigation__box--active')) {
                document
                    .querySelector('.navigation__box--active')
                    .classList.remove('navigation__box--active');

                // Use value of captured attribute (href) to target and toggle the new active class
                document
                    .querySelector(clicked)
                    .classList.toggle('navigation__box--active');

                // Not found any active css class (box)
            } else {
                let clicked = e.target.getAttribute('href');
                document
                    .querySelector(clicked)
                    .classList.toggle('navigation__box--active');
            }
        });
    });

    const openNavigation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        headerHamburger.classList.toggle('active');

        if (
            headerMenu.getAttribute('data-open') === headerMenuText.textContent
        ) {
            headerMenuText.textContent = headerMenu.getAttribute('data-close');
            navigation.classList.add('navigation--active');
        } else {
            headerMenuText.textContent = headerMenu.getAttribute('data-open');
            navigation.classList.remove('navigation--active');
        }
    };

    const closeNavigation = () => {
        if (document.querySelector('.navigation__box--active')) {
            document
                .querySelector('.navigation__box--active')
                .classList.remove('navigation__box--active');
        }

        if (document.querySelector('.navigation__link--active')) {
            document
                .querySelector('.navigation__link--active')
                .classList.remove('navigation__link--active');
        }
    };

    navigationClose.forEach((close) => {
        close.addEventListener('click', closeNavigation);
    });

    headerMenu.addEventListener('click', openNavigation);
})();
```

Is there a way this can be solved?

Comment: Try this as a quick workaround : `font { pointer-events: none; }` to stop catching click events and become inert to the mouse cursor

Comment: EDITED my code JS is pretty large. Please take a look.

Comment: Wow, font { pointer-events: none; } Did it! thank you very much. Damn, feel so stupid....